# shrink the size of the font size in the listing

Tags: beamer, listings

I am using the latex beamer and trying to reduce the font size of the listing to display the whole JSON code without reducing the font size of the sentence before. How can I get it to work?

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\JSONnumbervaluestyle{\color{red}}
\newcommand\JSONstringvaluestyle{\color{red}}

% switch used as state variable
\newif\ifcolonfoundonthisline

\makeatletter

\lstdefinestyle{json}
{
  showstringspaces    = false,
  alsoletter          = 0123456789.,
  morestring          = [s]{"}{"},
  stringstyle         = \ifcolonfoundonthisline\JSONstringvaluestyle\fi,
  MoreSelectCharTable =%
    \lst@DefSaveDef{`:}\colon@json{\processColon@json},
  basicstyle          = \ttfamily,
  keywordstyle        = \ttfamily\bfseries,
}

% flip the switch if a colon is found in Pmode
\newcommand\processColon@json{%
  \colon@json%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \global\colonfoundonthislinetrue%
  \fi
}

\lst@AddToHook{Output}{%
  \ifcolonfoundonthisline%
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
      \def\lst@thestyle{\JSONnumbervaluestyle}%
    \fi
  \fi
  %override by keyword style if a keyword is detected!
  \lsthk@DetectKeywords% 
}

% reset the switch at the end of line
\lst@AddToHook{EOL}%
  {\global\colonfoundonthislinefalse}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title{Test}
\author{Alex XYZ}
\institute{University XYZ}
\date{20.01.16}



\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{JSON array of the timetable sheets}

JSON array of the parsed timetable sheets:
\bigbreak


\begin{lstlisting}[style=json]

        [{"stops": [{
                     "arrival_time": {
                                       "mon-fri": [ "04:31", "04:43"],
                                      "sat":     ["05:32", "06:32"],                                     
                                      "sun":     ["05:32", "06:32"]
                                      },   
                     "stop_name": "XYZ",
                     "stop_lat": "90.874136",
                     "stop_long": "19.665553"
                    }]
         }]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the font size to your basicstyle, e.g.,

```
basicstyle = \ttfamily\small,
```

Of course, with that dramatic indentation, you need much smaller fonts:

If you do

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=json,basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny]
        [{"stops": [{
                     "arrival_time": {
                                       "mon-fri": [ "04:31", "04:43"],
                                      "sat":     ["05:32", "06:32"],
                                      "sun":     ["05:32", "06:32"]
                                      },
                     "stop_name": "XYZ",
                     "stop_lat": "90.874136",
                     "stop_long": "19.665553"
                    }]
         }]
\end{lstlisting}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: Or with a listing specific option: `\begin{lstlisting}{style=json,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small]` Also `\footnotesize` can be tried.

Comment: @alaferg: I added `\small` to this `basicstyle = \ttfamily ` line but nothing changed.

Comment: @egreg: I tried your first version too but without success. Where can I use `\footnotesize`?

Comment: @TheBook I added an example

Comment: I just compiled your MWE via pdflatex and the font size is changing as expected. You can try `\footnotesize` in place of `\small` in the basicstyle. Or even smaller to get it to fit. Note also that lstlisting is a verbatim environment. So you may need to delete some of the initial spaces to move your code statements more to the left so they will fit on the slide.

Comment: @egreg: Yes it works with `tiny` but nothing changed with `\footnotesize`.